# Custom FileDialog in WinCE 6.0

Tags: c++, winapi, mfc, windows-ce

I am newbie in WinCE Programming, i want to Create Custom File Dialog for our application, which has totally diffrent look and feel than the default windows file dialog....
I looked into many Flag value bt they won't worth it ...

Any pointers will be helpful
Thnks...
Mukesh

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what level you're looking at replacing it.  Do you want to replace it device-wide, or just for your app?  If it's just for your app, create a new Dialog with the features you want and call it.

To replace it system-wide you have to have the ability (i.ee tools and BSP) to create a new OS image.  You would clone the following folder in your project tree:

`%WINCEROOT%\PUBLIC\SHELL\OAK\HPC\CESHELL\UI`

Then modify the resource (and potentially code) files you want changes and rebuild your OS.